# next js app not loading .css and .js on nginx (404)

Tags: nginx, next.js

My next js application is not loading the .css and .js files i keep getting 404 on those
this is my /etc/nginx/sites-available/default:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

location / {
    # reverse proxy for next server
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    alias /root/Git/EcoBL/.next/static;
    add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=3600, immutable";
    # we need to remove this 404 handling
    # because next's _next folder and own handling
    # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

i'm using :
pm2 start yarn --name "nextjs" --interpreter bash -- start